# Rotational Torque Versus Thrust on a Screw

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, torque, estimation

We all used screws and tightening them before, but here is my question.  If a Thrust-like load behind the other side of the screw can move the screw out (example pushing), then how much force is it requred (push only) for it to move the screw in rotation?[image: Its a crude drawing of a screw but here is what I am trying to solve]

Comment: I've deleted my answer because I don't need the down votes. Mike's answer is hardly an answer: 'it's pressure' explains nothing. I suggest you carry out a simple experiment. Try and push **w/o torque** a screw into butter. This way friction is minimal. See if you get any spontaneous rotation. I say you won't. Meanwhile I await Mike's *mathematical* explanation.

Comment: Geez Gert, you do get prickly when people disagree with you.  Did you downvote this question, too?

Comment: @Mike: I did not down vote, nor did I vote to close. Nor did I get "prickly". I simply disagree with you. The push drill is interesting but far removed from the OP's question. The 'butter challenge' still stands. :-) Please do yourself observe etiquette here: don't *falsely* accuse people of down voting!

Comment: @Gert (1) I don't believe you understand how a push drill works; it's the exact same principle.  (2) Feel free to satisfy your curiosity with the butter challenge; I am confident enough that if I were able to eliminate torque from whatever I use to push the screw would turn, and do not wish to waster butter.  (3) Asking is different from accusing.  I accept that you were not the downvoter, now that you've said it.  But I do feel that deleting an answer you believe to be correct is bad form, even if you picked up a couple downvotes for it.

Comment: @Mike: any member 'owns' his own answers and can do what them what they want. If it was 'bad form' (another accusation) it wouldn't be allowed by this site to delete one. I'm under no obligation to incur further down votes if I don't want to. It's one of the reasons why I only very rarely down vote anything. The 'butter challenge' was really directed at OP, not you. I'm sorry if I didn't make that clear.

Comment: To be clear, I don't have a general problem with deleting your own question.  But I think you should have the integrity to defend your claims if you believe them to be correct until you change your mind and admit that you're wrong, the downvoters change their minds, or upvoters come along to agree with you.  That's basically how science works.  Also... accusation?  You keep using that word.  I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: Oops, i made a slight mistake on the diagram, the rotational force exerts to the right side of the triangle, the bottom represented how much length it progressed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't have to consider the inertia of the screw (which is always), these problems can easily be analyzed by unwinding the screw to a plane (as you've done in your figure).  So think of the screw and the surface of contact as two inclined planes that slide against each other (one on top and one beneath it).

Now, pushing on the screw is like pushing vertically down onto the top inclined plane, which does two important things: 1) there is a component of this force that will act to slide one plane along the other; 2) there is a component of this force which will increase the normal, and therefore increase the friction.  So, **here's the trick**:

These two force will both scale in proportion to the downward force.  That is, for shallow angles, the planes will never slide against each other because as the downward force increase, so does the frictional force.  (This is, btw, a [common trick for measuring the coefficient of friction](http://physics.bu.edu/~duffy/semester1/c6_measuremus.html): by measuring the angle of the applied force where one object will slide over another.)

*Therefore, pushing on a screw will never make it turn because the angle is too shallow in relation to the coefficient of friction.*  On the other hand, one can make useful device with steeper angle, as Mike suggested, and pushing on these will cause them to turn.

Comment: Does this same principle apply to lobes too? Just wondering

Comment: @ImOnlyAI does this apply to lobes as well?

Answer (score 1):

Gareth, this is a good first question.  You've asked it well, and I encourage you to ask more questions in the future.

Basically, you can just reverse any usual explanation of a screw.  Normally, the wedge transfers torque into thrust; well in this case the wedge transfers thrust into torque — it's exactly the same, but reversed.  This is a special example of a fact that you'll find throughout classical physics: as long as there is no dissipation, you can just reverse any process.  In this case, friction is the main source of dissipation, so if you can reduce the friction enough, you can make it work.

Look up "push drill" to see an example of a machine that works on this principle, as in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9BaWEVgPriE&t=0m50s).  (I think I've also seen these called "Yankee" drills.)  The drill contains a big screw, and the handle contains bearings to reduce friction as the handle slides over that screw.  You push the handle towards the tip, and the tip rotates as a result.  The screw's threads are very long, which gives the drill a good amount of mechanical advantage, just like a very slightly sloped incline, which means you get a good amount of torque on whatever you're driving.  In the video, they show the push drill driving a drill going into drywall and a screw going into wood.  In fact, you can even see in that video that it's possible to exert torque that backs that screw out of the wood, even though she's pushing *forward* on the drill handle (toward the wood).

[My grandpa had a push drill that I used to play with as a small child.  I think it might be what made me a physics nerd all those years ago.]

Comment: Although the drill isnt exactly the same type of example i seek yet it does somehow.  The example was on a stationary bolted bolt or crewed in screw, but, as for the "push" driver, it does it similar, convertinf reciporating force into rotational.  TY for making it clear to me (because often i will misunderstand)

Comment: Do you know if this applies to lobes like cam lobes too?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.  If you push on a cam in the appropriate position, then you can get it turn — again assuming friction is not a problem.  That is, you can convert linear motion into rotation, as opposed to the usual function of a cam which involves converting rotation into linear motion.

Comment: Ty, I was trying to make a fail safe device on my invention and by applying this principle I can get it to work